# Maximum number of prime sums

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Zach thinks of six different positive integers, and for each pair of numbers, he adds them. This gives him $\binom{6}{2}=15$ sums. Among these sums, find the maximum number that can be prime numbers. I deducted that there has to be atleast one even number among the $6$ numbers. But will there be one even number, or two evens. Then what will the other numbers be.

Comment: By "one $2$" presumably you mean at least one even number?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. I just wrote what was in my mind.

Comment: To be clear, 0 would be allowed as well? It that case I believe that you would at least be able to get 10 prime numbers by using 3 odd and 3 even integers, two of which would have to be 0 and 2, and the odd numbers would have to be primes.

Comment: @fibonatic "positive" in English descriptions excludes zero. I know that other languages have variations on that though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The sum of two different positive integers is always at least $3$, and so in order for it to be prime, it has to be odd. So one summand has to be even, the other odd. If there are $a$ even numbers and $b = 6-a$ odd numbers, then the potential number of primes is at most $ab \leq 9$, attained when $a=b=3$. Can this bound be attained? Here is an example:
$$
2,3,4,8,9,15.
$$
All of the following are primes:
$$
2+3 = 5 \\
3+4 = 7 \\
2+9 = 3 + 8 = 11 \\
4+9 = 13 \\
2+15 = 8+9 = 17 \\
4+15 = 19 \\
8+15 = 23
$$
If you don't like the repeated sums, you can try instead:
$$
2,3,4,8,39,99.
$$
All of the following are prime:
$$
2+3 = 5 \\
3+4 = 7 \\
3+8 = 11 \\
2+39 = 41 \\
4+39 = 43 \\
8+39 = 47 \\
2+99 = 101 \\
4+99 = 103 \\
8+99 = 107
$$

Comment: You can use {2,6,12,5,17,41} to maximize the number of primes in the original set :-)

Comment: @Joffan: neat, did you determine that by trial and error? or else how?

Comment: @Joffan: [2,5,6,12,17 (without 41)](http://oeis.org/search?q=+2%2C5%2C6%2C12%2C17&sort=&language=&go=Search) pops up in a couple of different OEIS sequences

Comment: @smci - a pre-existing list of primes, good spreadsheet design and a little trial and error. I rejected some alternatives that had duplicate sums. It's no surprise to me that those numbers pop up in some sequences - the law of small numbers.

Comment: @Joffan: you have discovered a new interesting sequence worthy of [submitting to OEIS](http://oeis.org/Submit.html), please do!!! Now can you generalize to N=8, 10... integers with C(N,2) distinct prime sums? Is it always possible for even N?